# What would be the regex for this pattern; (alphanumeric.alphanumeric.alphanumeric)?

Tags: regex

I am new to regex. What would be the regex for this pattern?

(alphanumeric string.alphanumeric string.alphanumeric string)

- spaces not allowed
- not fixed length
- the 3 alphanumeric strings must be within the parentheses
- string cannot be empty

Example #1
(abcdelkeksebct1.ct.abceng)

Example #2
(efcdelkeksebnyc2.nyc1.efg2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
/\((\w+\.\w+\.\w+)\)/
```

Sample: https://regex101.com/r/fC2zJ4/1

Comment: Hi Martin, I need to allow the dash character in the alphanumeric group. The current reg expression does not work for this.

Comment: Such as abc-delkeksebct1.ct-1.abc-eng